# MongoDb and Spring Data: project new array field

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

How to implement the following Mongo DB query using Spring Data?

```
db.getCollection('docs').aggregate([
   { 
       $project: { 
          values: [ "$a", "$b" ] 
       } 
   }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AggregationOperation projectStage = Aggregation.project()
    .andArrayOf("$a","$b").as("values");
```